# Programmatically detect install type

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I'm developing an electron application, and I need a way to programmatically detect if the currently running application was installed using an .msi installer or an .exe installer. There are certain features of my application that I need to disable if the user installed with .msi. Is it possible to detect this in my node.js app code?